# Pandas Groupby and create new column with custom values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Folks,

I've searched StackOverflow for my use-case but haven't been able to find anything useful. If you feel this problem is already solved, please point to the appropriate question.

Use-case.

I have the following data-frame.

```
  Maturity,Periods  
  0.5,2   
  0.5,2   
  1.0,3  
  1.0,3   
  1.0,3
```

As you can see, the `maturity` column is repeated based on the number in the `periods` column. Now what I want to accomplish is create a new column which will have all 0s except 1 value for each grouped maturity. So expected dataframe is something like this

```
  Maturity,Periods,CP   
  0.5,2,0  
  0.5,2,1   
  1.0,3,0    
  1.0,3,0   
  1.0,3,1
```

As you can see in the expected dataframe, the number of `0s` in the `CP` column is 1 less than the value in the `Periods` column and the remaining value is 1.

I tried the below pandas groupby operation but it fails.

```
new_df['CP'] = new_df.groupby(['Maturity'])['Periods'].apply(lambda x: np.zeros((x-1, 1)) + np.array([1.0])).reset_index()
```

Can somebody point out where am I going wrong?

**UPDATED EDIT:**

As a follow-up to the above question, how would the below approach be solved using Pandas' operations?

Using this above dataframe, I want to create new column but the expected output is something like this:

```
Maturity,Periods,CP,TimeCF  
0.5,2,0,0.5
0.5,2,1,0.5

1.0,3,0,0.5
1.0,3,0,1.0
1.0,3,1,1.0

1.5,4,0,0.5
1.5,4,0,1.0
1.5,4,0,1.5
1.5,4,1,1.5
```

The new column of `TimeCF` will have values of time of the cash flows (considering semi-annual cash flows of the bond)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem like you need a `groupby` here... try this:

```
df['CP'] = 0
df.loc[df['Maturity'].ne(df['Maturity'].shift(-1)), 'CP'] = 1

print(df)
   Maturity  Periods  CP
0       0.5        2   0
1       0.5        2   1
2       1.0        3   0
3       1.0        3   0
4       1.0        3   1
```

---

If `groupby` is unavoidable, you can use it in a similar fashion as before:

```
df['CP'] = 0
df.loc[df.groupby('Maturity').apply(lambda x: x.index[-1]), 'CP'] = 1

print(df)
   Maturity  Periods  CP
0       0.5        2   0
1       0.5        2   1
2       1.0        3   0
3       1.0        3   0
4       1.0        3   1
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Didn't know about this `ne` operation before. Thanks.

Comment: How would you solve the updated question edit? I tried using some combination of groupby and reset_index() but couldn't get as expected.

Comment: @sgokhales I'm not at my desk now, so if you could wait a few hours, I'll take a look at it. Otherwise, if you're in a hurry, I'd suggest opening a new question as an extension to this one

Comment: np. you can check later.

Comment: @sgokhales Okay, can you please explain this: "The new column of TimeCF will have values of time of the cash flows (considering semi-annual cash flows of the bond)" you just said a lot of things with little context (what are cash flows? bond? semi-annual?)

Comment: What I meant was this: If you have a semi-annual bond, that means at each 0.5 year interval, you are paid some stipend (called coupon) and at maturity, you're paid the whole principal back. So if it's a 3 year bond with semi-annual cash flows, then coupon is paid 6 times essentially (at t=0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3) and the original principal is paid back at the end of maturity of bond (i.e t = 6). Hope this helps. :)